# Getting null value when trying to instantiate Model class in another Action Method in the same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi need help on the below please.

**Step 1 :** I have a controller named "**Managing**" that has two methods. "**AllStudent**" and "**StudentDetails**" methods.

**AllStudent** action method fetches data from endpoint API and display it in to **AllStudent** View. 
Inside "**AllStudent**" action method I have a Json line that mapps to **AllStudentModel** (*Please see below*)

**I DID NOT create a CONSTRUCTOR for it ???  Is it not a issue??**

```
  public class AllStudentModel
    {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public string Course { get; set; }
            public string Picture { get; set; }
    }



//Action method AllStudent
public async Task<ActionResult> AllStudent()
{
  //Fetching data thru webapi... in a foreach loop
  ...

  List<AllStudentModel> stdList = new List<AllStudentModel>();

  stdList.Add(PropertyDetails);

  return View(stdList);

}
```

Inside **AllStudent** View, on top of the page I have this statement ( **@model IEnumerable** ) and I'm able to get data using foreach loop. (*please see below*)

```
foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.Id))
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</p>
    <img style="width: 100%" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Picture)" alt="Image">
    ...
}
```

So far everything works great, I mean I'm able to display the retrieved data in AllStudentView.

What I must display in **AllStudentView** is only : The student Id, Student Picture and Student Name for all the students, and I'm able to display it properly and it's working fine. (Please see below picture.)

[PICTURE HERE !!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTR43.png)

*If the user click on "View More Details" for one student, it must be able to pick the selected Id, and redirect it to another page where the user need to see all the details for the selected student by Id.*

**Step 2 :** I have another action method named "**studentDetails**" inside the same "**Managing**" controller that needs to display all the details (property model) for a selected student.

Inside **studentDetails** action method, when I try to instantiate "**AllStudentModel**" I got null value when running and debugging it !!!  Not sure why ???

**StudentDetails** action method has got no Model created for it as I'm using the same Model as "AllStudentModel" because it's the same template of data !!!

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult StudentDetails(int? id)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("Id selected by user : " + id);     // This line is working fine as I'm able to see the Id the user selected from "AllStudentView" when he clicks "View More Details"


        // ++++++ GETTING NULL VALUE FOR ALL THE BELOW WHILE DEBUGGING ++++++ 


        var stdModel = new AllStudentModel();

        Debug.WriteLine(stdModel.Id);                       // Getting Null value from all the below                                
        Debug.WriteLine(stdModel.Title);                    // Getting Null value from all the below
        Debug.WriteLine(stdModel.Name);                     // Getting Null value from all the below
        Debug.WriteLine(stdModel.Surname);                  // Getting Null value from all the below
        Debug.WriteLine(stdModel.Course);                   // Getting Null value from all the below
        Debug.WriteLine(stdModel.Picture);                  // Getting Null value from all the below

    }
```

So far, I'm not using any interaction to the DataBase !!!

***Someone told me I need a CONSTRUCTOR for "AllStudentModel" to initialize the properties.  is it true???***

**In Step 1, everything is working perfectly fine !!!
Only step 2 that I'm getting null value**

Why I'm unable to get data from "studentDetails" action method ?

Can you please assist?

===========================================================================

Also I wanted to add that : I'm fetching data from api and loading this data to Model as below : using only **PropertyDetailsList.Add(PropertyDetails);** instead of maybe... ***PropertyDetailsList.Add(New PropertyDetails);*** as seen [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/788784/Using-Model-to-pass-data-to-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

```
                if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    APIdatas2 = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        PropertyDetailsModel PropertyDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PropertyDetailsModel>(APIdatas2);

                        stringJsonConv = PropertyDetails;

                        PropertyDetailsList.Add(PropertyDetails);

                        Debug.WriteLine("ID ALREADY PROCESSED : " + item.Id);

                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error occurred, the status code is : {0}", response2.StatusCode);
                }
```

Comment: Please show the full code on your student details action method so you can get appropriate support.

Comment: which value is null exactly? `var stdModel = new AllStudentModel();` creates a brand new student object with nothing in it. So quite likely the values within it will be null, yes. Did you want to take the ID submitted from the browser (when the user selected a student) and fetch the details from the database, perhaps? It's bit unclear, since you didn't show anywhere near enough code for us to understand correctly. Please edit your question. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code that loads model values? here you are created a new `AllStudentModel` object and it will be null only.where you are assigning the values to model? If you are not interacting with database,use `constructor` to initialize it OR you can assign it from the controller as `stdModel.Title="TEST";`, `stdModel.Name="Sophia";`and so on

Comment: I edited it again. I'm assigning the value to Model thru List

Answer (score 0):

> I DID NOT create a CONSTRUCTOR for it ??? Is it not a issue??

If you do not specify a constructor for a class, C# with internally create a default constructor for it. The default values for data types can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table).

> var stdModel = new AllStudentModel();

In your student details method you are instantiating a new student model, but you are not mapping any data to it. C# defaults the values of properties as per table in the link above. That is why the properties on stdModel are null (or 0 in case of int properties).

You will need to map some data to stdModel before sending it to your view, like you are doing with AllStudentModel.

> AllStudent action method fetches data from endpoint API and display it in to AllStudent View. Inside "AllStudent" action method I have a Json line that mapps to AllStudentModel (Please see below)

Comment: So, how to map data to it?

Comment: So How would I map some data to stdModel??  I don't have the data/source in **StudentDetails** action method. All data are remained in AllStudent View.  I'm able to pass data from **AllStudent** to **StudentDetails** action method thru webApi using TempData but I don't want this way of doing things.

Comment: Either make another API call and bind the data to the stdModel, or save the fetched data in an in memory repository or a database and map it to stdModel from there.

Comment: Maybe I only **mapped** it to stdModel but have not bound it. So how do I bound it to stdModel ?

Comment: What is surprising me is that there is data in the **@model IEnumerable<ABC.Web.Models.Managing.AllStudentModel>** which I retrieve in **AllStudentView** to display.. and it's work fine.  but I **CAN'T** use the same data in another method !!!

Comment: @sophia web applications are _stateless_. Data values are not preserved in memory between requests, and different action methods don't have access to each other's data. And your code isn't even trying to access such data anyway, it's just creating a brand new, empty copy of the allstudentmodel class. The only item of data which is passed into your `StudentDetails` is the ID of the student. You need to use that ID to request the correct details again from the data source and populate the object